# Polar coordinates and Jacobian of $\frac12 r $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To solve a double integral problem, I just did the sub 
$$x = \frac12 r \cos( \theta )
, \quad
y = r \sin( \theta )$$
and the Jacobian is $\frac12 r $ but I realise – I'm not sure how to write that determinant, sure it has to be 1/2 in front of $\sin (\theta)$ in position 1,1 in the determinant, but where is the logic behind that.

Comment: Just go step by step. $a_{11}=x'_{r}, a_{12}=x'_{\theta}, a_{21}=y'_{r}$ and $a_{22}=y'_{\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I hope what's below helps you.

You have $x(r,\theta)=\dfrac r 2\cos(\theta)$ and $y(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)$, for all $r,\theta$ somewhere.

It follows that
$$\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}(r,\theta)= \dfrac 1 2\cos(\theta),& \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}(r,\theta)=-\dfrac r 2\sin(\theta)\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}(r,\theta)=\sin(\theta), & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}(r,\theta)=r\cos(\theta)
\end{cases}$$

So $$\left|\begin{matrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}(r,\theta) & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}(r,\theta)\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}(r,\theta) & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}(r,\theta) \end{matrix}\right| = \left|\begin{matrix}\dfrac 1 2\cos(\theta) & -\dfrac r 2\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{matrix}\right|=\dfrac r 2.$$

Comment: of course, by definition. this is an answer to my question. thanks.

Comment: @jacob No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian $|J|= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
D_1x & D_2x  \\
D_1y & D_2y \\
 \end{array} \right|= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac 1 2 \cos(\theta) & - \frac 1 2 r\sin(\theta)  \\
 \sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)  \\
\end{array} \right|= \frac 1 2 r$